# Kubernetes pod can't mount NFS directory, permission denied

Tags: kubernetes, permissions, mount, nfs

Under Hyper-v I've create two Ubuntu VMs.  The first creates a nfs server for /srv/nfs. /etc/exports
/srv/nfs *(rw,sync,no_root_squash)
The second can easily mount the nfs file system with this command as root or any user
mount -t nfs 192.168.1.40:/srv/nfs /mnt/nfs
so nfs server and client works great between the VMs.
I start an alpine Kubernetes pod under windows docker, and remote shell into the pod.
I can ping 192.168.1.40 fine under 1ms from the pod
but the nfs mount command above always says...
mount: /mnt/nfs: permission denied.
The pod /mnt/nfs directory is present and I did a chmod 777 /mnt/nfs
Worked on this for a couple days, but I'm baffled.

I beleive by default pods have complete egress permissions and the ping works fine.  What is failing here?
The pod is root, so if root works for a VM why doesn't it work for a pod as root?  What component in K8s is restricting this from completing?

Comment: can you give us more details like which kubernetes version you are using and your deployment manifest file or some steps for replicating the issue.

Comment: Kubernetes deployment is WSL2.  I am just trying to connect an Alpine pod to an nfs server, of which I can connect through another VM, as root or any login.   All I can come up with is Kubernetes is restricting the egress.  Permission denied does tell you much.  I am at a loss of what to try next.

Comment: I am connecting to the alpine pod with and exec -- sh command.  And then trying to mount the nfs server through the shell cmd mentioned above, which fails.  My yaml file also fails, but It seems irrelevant, since I can not mount if manually as well.

Comment: Hello Robert while the information you provided outlines the process it is not sufficient for replicating the issue. Kindly refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidelines on asking a question on StackEx.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to mount the NFS server on the VM from WSL2 and K8s pods by adding 'insecure' to the following line in /etc/exports on my NFS server.

```
/srv/nfs        *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,insecure)
```

I believe that the other VM was able to mount it because it used a client port below 1024.  I believe that WSL2, and windows Docker/K8s use a client port above 1024 which by default, NFS server will reject if insecure is not allowed.

Additionally *(...) allows any client ip address to connect but you would want to replace * with the ip addresses of your clients to restrict who can connect to the NFS server.